# get objects that json file contains with jackson and java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON file like that:

```
{"city":[  
  {  
     "id":"c1",
     "name":"Paris",
     "population":2125851,
     "département":"075"
  },
  {  
     "id":"c2",
     "name":"Marseille",
     "population":797491,
     "département":"013"
  }],"person":[  
  {  
     "id":"p1",
     "name":"Jules Verne",
     "born":"c6",
     "category":"cat3",
     "birthdate":"1828-02-08"
  },
  {  
     "id":"p2",
     "name":"René Coty",
     "born":"c11",
     "category":"cat2",
     "birthdate":"1882-03-20"
  }]}
```

And I need to extract the objects names, so I need to get here "city" and "person".
I tried with jackson some thing like that:

```
JsonParser jParser = null;
            JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
            jParser = jfactory.createJsonParser(new File("graph.gjson"));
            while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {

                  String fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
                  jParser.nextToken();
                  System.out.println(jParser.getText());
```

But this doesn't work, any one can help me please?

Comment: what error does it throws

Comment: it just diplay for me this :
city
{
c1
Paris
2125851
075

Comment: do not parse it like that instead use methods provided by jackson. library .https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: I saw that tutorial but I don't need to convert my json to POJO

Comment: you don't need to or you don't want to? if you want to parse it as text file by yourself then you need some boilerplate code. your while loop condition is not correctly terminating the loop

Comment: I don't want to convert, yeah I know there is some thing missing or not correct that's why I'm asking for help

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution

```
Object obj;
                try {
                    obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(json));
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                    Set<String> keys = jsonObject.keySet();
                    java.util.Iterator<String> key= keys.iterator();
                    while(key.hasNext())
                    {    Object element = key.next();
                        System.out.println(element);
                    }



                } catch (IOException | org.json.simple.parser.ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I wanted to share it with you for those who will search same thing like me, so the output here is gonna be the objects names "keys" which are city and person.

Answer (score 0):

update your while loop condition to `while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY)` this will let you parse through the whole array instead of just singleobject

**Update** a more general solution for parsing everything

```
    JsonToken token = jParser.nextToken() ;
    while (token != null && token != JsonToken.END_OBJECT)
    {

        String fieldname = jParser.getCurrentName();
        if (fieldname != null)
        {
            token = jParser.nextToken();
            System.out.println(jParser.getText());
        }
        token = jParser.nextToken();
        if (token == JsonToken.END_OBJECT)
            token = jParser.nextToken();

    }
```

Comment: but this doesn't display for me "city" and "person" :(

Comment: This will give you everything in your file

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) if you don't want to cast your JSONs to POJOs, just want to extract some values from it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String json = ...;
    final List<String> personNames = JsonPath.read(json, "$.person[*].name");
    final List<String> cityNames = JsonPath.read(json, "$.city[*].name");

    System.out.println(personNames);
    System.out.println(cityNames);
}
```